# How to activate chosen() for my dropdown box

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, drop-down-menu, haml, jquery-chosen

I am using [chosen()](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to implement my drop down box.

In my home page, I set the drop down box as with the following code

```
//Code in home template
.bookmark_questions
  %select
    %option{value: "xxxx"} xxxxxx
    %option{value: "xxxx"} xxxxxx
    %option{value: "xxxx"} xxxxxx
    %option{value: "xxxx"} xxxxxx

//Code in home view
render: ->
  $(@el).html @template()
  @$('select').chosen()
  @
```

In my home view, I try to activate chosen by "`@$('select').chosen()`", however when I try to run the code, I get the following error

> this.search_field[0] is undefined

[image]

What is the right way to activate chosen for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is quite old, but I just had almost the same issue and what fixed the issue was waiting to call the plugin until after the `select`'s were attached to the `DOM`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was a timing issue. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone might call `render()` before your DOM is ready, at the mean time, `chosen` can't find the element your specify. Here is my solution:

First, add a DOM ready block at the end of coffee/js file, top level.

```
$ ->
  $('.bookmark_questions select').chosen()
```

Then let Backbone.View tell `chosen` to update items while the view is ready

```
render: ->
  @$el.trigger('liszt:updated')
```